# Why doesn't IE7- display this CSS properly

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I set up a search box using divs and floats to create a multiple column layout.  My IE 7- clients see a line break between the `filter-label` and `filter-input-controls`.

[image: line break]

They have corporate policies that won't let them upgrade or use Chrome or FF.  I tried using a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/794234) and a [comment before the doctype](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/wNMbod1neKE).  No luck.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgF5V/)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using LABEL tags and a styled, unordered list, as a container for your form elements. This results in cleaner code and it makes more semantic sense.

See: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your search box is too wide. Try adding a `*width:` to the containing `div`. The `*` is a filter for IE7 and below.

IE7 will need everything spelled out layout wise (width, height, float, etc). If one element is too large, it will break the layout. More modern browsers are more forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your "Deviation Status" span is in a different div than your select, one would expect them to be displayed in different block elements.  As I don't see "display:inline(or inline-block);" anywhere in your CSS, it doesn't look like you are accounting for this default behavior..